# Alpha release 'Deployed' but unavailable

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have built a Google Action using Dialogflow and having trouble releasing an updated version to Alpha today.

The updated action works OK in Draft and I submitted it for Alpha deployment. The Actions console is showing the release as "Deployed". However, when I try to access the Alpha version I get an "isn't responding right now" response (from the simulator, Home device and Assistant smartphone app). The backend fulfilment service which is shared by Draft and Alpha is working OK.

I can see the following in the Debug console on the simulator:

```
{
  "response": "MyAction Test isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "EucBS2o5Uk...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAAP+H...",
  "ssmlMarkList": [],
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=XXXXX&versionId=20' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: XXXXX'  -A Google-ActionsOnGoogle/1.0 -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"accessToken\":\"eyXXXXX\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2019-09-12T09:58:03Z\",\"userStorage\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"welcomes\\\":53,\\\"intentCounts\\\":{\\\"BALANCE\\\":2}}}\",\"userVerificationStatus\":\"VERIFIED\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABXXXXXX\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"Talk to MyAction Test\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"accessToken\":\"eyXXXXX\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2019-09-12T09:58:03Z\",\"userStorage\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"welcomes\\\":53,\\\"intentCounts\\\":{\\\"BALANCE\\\":2}}}\",\"userVerificationStatus\":\"VERIFIED\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABXXXXX\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"Talk to MyAction Test\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}",
      "delegatedRequest": {
        "delegatedRequest": ""
      }
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\"><title>Error 400 (Not Found)!!1</title><style nonce=\"2YtDuE0THEDAcE3p1uuIgA\">*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{color:#222;text-align:unset;margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px;}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}pre{white-space:pre-wrap;}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}</style><div id=\"af-error-container\"><a href=//www.google.com><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a><p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins><p>The requested URL was not found on this server. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins></div>",
      "delegatedResponse": {
        "delegatedResponse": ""
      }
    },
    "sharedDebugInfoList": [],
    "conversationBuilderExecutionEventsList": []
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "MyAction Test isn't responding right now. Try again soon."
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": true,
  "clientOperationList": [
    {
      "operationType": 4,
      "startIndicatorPayLoad": {
        "status": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "operationType": 7,
      "exitIndicatorPayLoad": {
        "status": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "projectName": "",
  "renderedHtml": ""
}
```

And the Stackdriver log is showing:

```
2019-09-12 11:56:49.381 BST   App returned an HTTP error. State: URL_ERROR
{
 insertId: "1iedwiug2dbgn68"  
 labels: {
  channel: "preview"   
  querystream: "GOOGLE_USER"   
  source: "AOG_REQUEST_RESPONSE"   
 }
 logName: "projects/myaction-test/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-09-12T10:56:49.389233862Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type: "assistant_action"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "App returned an HTTP error. State: URL_ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2019-09-12T10:56:49.381445860Z"  
 trace: "projects/XXXXX/traces/ABXXXXX"  
}
```

Looking at Dialogflow, the Environments / versions view shows the status of the release as "Deploying", so there seems to be a mismatch between the Action and Dialogflow deployments..?

I have tried re-releasing to Alpha (original attempt was nearly 4 hours ago), but the same problem/ errors still exist. Both attempted releases are showing as "Deploying" in Dialogflow.

Has anyone seen this before? Any idea what the problem may be or how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No solution yet but I have opened a support request with logs that have the same error.

Haven't received a support response yet but did find a workaround.
Inside of the Dialogflow agent settings > Environments and under draft I was able to view all versions. The latest version that I was looking for did say "Ready". When I clicked on the three dots to the right I loaded it to draft. Then in the Actions on Google console I went to Deploy, then the alpha section and clicked "Submit for alpha". Almost immediately after deploying and seeing "Deployed", the skill was available again for the alpha users.

Definitely don't remember doing this previously.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried a release again this morning and it seems to be working again. I also raised a support ticket with Google, but haven't heard anything from them regarding the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a response from Google who said there was an "issue" that day. Seems to be working OK now